# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in javascript function

Tags: javascript

i am trying to make cart list of my web. It's working fine in the hosted website but when i download it at home and make it as localhost it give me error.

here is the code line

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#widget_tb_purchase').dataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": false,
      "ordering": false,
      "info": false,
      "autoWidth": false,
      "sDom": 'lfrtip',
      "scrollCollapse": true,
      lengthMenu: [
          [ 5 ]
      ]
        });
  });
</script>
```

the spesific line that it said contain error

```
lengthMenu: [
              [ 5 ]
          ] <<< [this line]
```

and my computer at work office using window 7 32-bit, at home i'm using window 10 64-bit.

Comment: The error seems unrelated to the posted code?

Comment: i'm not really sure, because i have some problem that kinda like this.
`<? $no++; ?>` 
in pc office this is working but in my home pc it doesn't work must using `<?php $no++; ?> `

Comment: PHP shorttags like that are only supported in older versions of PHP, and shouldn't generally be used. The correct PHP tags are `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: sorry for the late response.
yes, but like i said. it's working at my office computer and working fine at hosted site as well. but it give me error message when i make it localhost at my home computer. i don't want to make false guide or something, i'm just giving additional information.

Comment: Well, as noted, there doesn't seem to anything in the posted code that would cause that error, chances are you have some other script above that one or something that isn't properly closed, or the PHP outputs something that isn't valid.